# Possible to pass object out of IF statement scope?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

Here's my code. The compiler is complaining about unused variables within the scope, and use of an undeclared variable out of scope. I understand that. The object would need to be declared before the IF statement so it's accessible from both sides. But here's the twist.

I can't pre-declare the object because what class the object will be from is dependent on the result of the IF statement. Here's the excerpt of code that I'm stuck on.

```
if (!([self.defaults valueForKey:@"unofficialAPIOn"])) {

        MALInterfaceController *interface = [[MALInterfaceController alloc]init];

    }
    else{

        MALControllerUnofficial *interface = [[MALControllerUnofficial alloc]init];

    }

    [interface verifyAuth:self.usernameField.text forPassword:self.passwordField.text];
```

Both MALInterfaceController and MALControllerUnofficial are basically the same class that have the same methods, etc but are tailored to two different API's. How can I pass the *interface object upwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state:

> Both MALInterfaceController and MALControllerUnofficial are basically the same class that have the same methods, etc but are tailored to two different API's.

You want to consider (a) using a common base class (b) using a protocol or maybe (c) using a class cluster - the last is more obscure so we'll skip that one. Adopting any of these will address your problem.

(a) Common base class. Define a class with the code that is a generic version of what your object does, say `MALControllerGeneric`, and then create `MALInterfaceController` and `MALControllerUnofficial` as subclasses which tailor the generic version for the two different cases. Before your `if` declare `interface` to be of type `MALControllerGeneric`.

(b) Declare the common methods your two classes must provide as a *protocol*, this lists the methods an class *conforming* to the protocol must implement. Then declare your two classes as implementing this protocol. In outline this is:

```
@protocol MALController

- (void) someCommonProcedure;
// etc.

@end

// inherit from NSObject, implement MALController protocol
@interface MALInterfaceController : NSObject<MALController> 

// declare methods peculiar to MALInterfaceController (if any)

@end

@implementation MALInterfaceController

// implement protocol
- (void) someCommonProcedure { ... }

...

@end
```

You then declare `interface` to be *any* object which implements the protocol:

```
id<MALController> interface;
```

This improves (static) type-checking compared to use the more generic `id` type.

The choice between (a) and (b) depends on factors such as how much common code can be shared etc., there is no general right answer - you have to pick what suits.

**Addendum - After Comment**

Using the protocol approach, you should have the code along the lines of:

```
id<MALController> interface;

if (![self.defaults valueForKey:@"unofficialAPIOn"])
   interface = [MALInterfaceController new];
else
   interface = [MALControllerUnofficial new];

[interface verifyAuth:self.usernameField.text forPassword:self.passwordField.text];
```

BTW did you mean to call `boolForKey:` rather than `valueForKey:` above?

Comment: I did exactly as you said (both A and B) and I'm have the same problem as with the above method. It initializes correctly within the IF statement, but once out of it it returns to type  MALAPIGeneric with a value of NIL. I'm baffled.

Comment: Have you removed the declarations *within* the `if` and replaced with just assignments to the variable declared *before* the `if`? Added code outline above.

Comment: It worked! I see what I was doing wrong. The biggest being I was creating new pointers to objects with the same name rather than re-assigning the one I already had. Thank you for clearing it up for me. Oh and yeah I caught the ValueForKey mistake already. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use the dynamic type id?

```
id interface;
if (!([self.defaults valueForKey:@"unofficialAPIOn"])) {

        interface = [[MALInterfaceController alloc]init];

    }
    else{

        interface = [[MALControllerUnofficial alloc]init];

    }

    (id<protocolWhichBothClassesConformTo>)[interface verifyAuth:self.usernameField.text forPassword:self.passwordField.text];
```

Also, does this not mean you should be looking at a refactor if two of your classes have 'same methods etc'

Worth reading https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: I tried "id interface" but it goes back to NIL once out of the IF statement. The compiler still complains about unused variables as well. I didn't think I'd need to use protocols, and my understanding of them isn't the strongest, but I think I'll look into it now. Thanks.

Comment: `interface` can't ever 'go back' after being assigned within the if condition.  How are you checking it's value?  I would set a breakpoint inside the if() or else conditions to ensure the MALController class is being initialized correctly (Likely a problem within their `init` method) and if it shows as being assigned there look deeper into your code to see where it may be set back to nil.  If it is nil 1 line after the [[alloc]init] command it means that there is a problem within the `MALController` class init method

Comment: I did set a breakpoint, and I can see that it's initializing correctly inside the IF statement, however once it's out of the IF statement it goes back to NIL. I definitely have "id interface" declared before the IF statement.